# Is it possible for a VS Code extension to enable or disable other extensions programmatically?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Can I enable/disable specific extensions in VS Code from other extension?

There are commands to enable/disable all extensions, but I found no commands or methods for specific extensions.

I'm creating an extension that manages extensions by groups, so I would like to control it by code, not manually.

Answer (score -2):

Doing manual disable/enable for specific extension is the best option for me.
Go to your extensions tab, select manage gear(*like setting icon*) and the choose disable in the pop up. This will disable that specific extension and prompt you to reload VS Code.